# Creating Package sqlplus

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to create a package from the following procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_rows
(pl_deptno dept.deptno%TYPE, pl_dname dept.dname%TYPE, pl_loc dept.loc%TYPE
) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dept 
(deptno,dname,loc) 
values ( pl_deptno,pl_dname,pl_loc);
commit;
end insert_rows;
/
```

So far this is my package sec which, creates fine

```
create or replace package fpf 
is
procedure insert_rows
   (p_deptno IN dept.deptno%TYPE,
    p_dname IN dept.dname%TYPE,
    p_loc IN dept.loc%TYPE);
end fpf;
/
```

But, when i create the package body, i get compilation errors, any ideas?

```
create or replace package body fpf
as
procedure insert_rows
   (p_deptno IN dept.deptno%TYPE,
    p_dname IN dept.dname%TYPE,
    p_loc IN dept.loc%TYPE)
as
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dept 
(deptno,dname,loc) 
values ( pl_deptno,pl_dname,pl_loc);
end insert_rows;
end fpf;
/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get compilation errors, you'll want to see what errors you received.  In SQL*Plus, you can do that using the command `show errors`

```
SQL> create or replace package body fpf
  2  as
  3  procedure insert_rows
  4     (p_deptno IN dept.deptno%TYPE,
  5      p_dname IN dept.dname%TYPE,
  6      p_loc IN dept.loc%TYPE)
  7  as
  8  BEGIN
  9  INSERT INTO dept
 10  (deptno,dname,loc)
 11  values ( pl_deptno,pl_dname,pl_loc);
 12  end insert_rows;
 13  end fpf;
 14  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY FPF:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
9/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/29    PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

The errors are telling you that the compiler thinks that the keyword at line 11, column 29 is a column name and that column names aren't allowed at that point in your code.  Line 11 column 29 is the `pl_loc` identifier.  Presumably, you didn't intend that to be a reference to a column name.  Presumably, you intended that to be the name of a parameter.  But Oracle doesn't recognize that identifier as the parameter.  This is because your parameter is named `p_loc` not `pl_loc` (note the extra `l`).

If you correct the name of all three parameters, the code compiles

```
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package body fpf
  2  as
  3  procedure insert_rows
  4     (p_deptno IN dept.deptno%TYPE,
  5      p_dname IN dept.dname%TYPE,
  6      p_loc IN dept.loc%TYPE)
  7  as
  8  BEGIN
  9  INSERT INTO dept
 10  (deptno,dname,loc)
 11  values ( p_deptno,p_dname,p_loc);
 12  end insert_rows;
 13* end fpf;
SQL> /

Package body created.
```