# Get SQL Plus to display more detailed errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

When installing my application, users must start SQL Plus and run an SQL script. This script contains creates many tables and many PL/SQL functions and triggers etc.

At the moment some of the functions are in the wrong order in the script and so users currently see a few "trigger created with compilation errors" type messages. I believe this is because the functions/triggers rely on other functions which means they cannot compile correctly.

What I would like to do is to find out which ones are failing and what the specific compilation error was instead of the rather vague warning I get at the moment. This way I can rearrange the functions in my install script and get no more warnings!

### UPDATE

I would also like the specific errors to be logged into a file. At the moment I'm using the SPOOL command to log things, so it would be great if the errors could be 'spooled' too.

Comment: You can add `show err` or `select * from all_error where name='<object_name>' order by sequence` after each compilation command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Package sqlplus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732150/creating-package-sqlplus)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can append `show errors;` after creation of procedures/triggers in order to see detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks! Will this show ALL errors that have happened throughout the script, or just the last one? And this will also be 'spooled' into my log file?

Comment: Yes it is spooled. Oracle Doc says *When you specify SHOW ERRORS with no arguments, SQL*Plus shows compilation errors for the most recently created or altered stored procedure. When you specify the type (function, procedure, package, package body, trigger, view, type, type body, dimension, or java class) and the name of the PL/SQL stored procedure, SQL*Plus shows errors for that stored procedure. For more information on compilation errors, see your PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference.* See here: [SHOW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12041.htm)

Comment: Ah OK so I would need to put show errors after EVERY function I wanted to compile.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `show err` or `select * from all_errors where name='<object_name>' order by sequence` after each compilation command.